# matAutocomplete display over the screen

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hi i am beginner for angular and i want to display material Autocompletion textview 
in ionic apps and i followed below blog to do my requirement https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview but when i run my code  it display over the screen like below image but i want to display below of input field like how they are display in their blog can some one suggest me please

### home.css

```
page-home {
  .example-form {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .example-full-width {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

### home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.name">
          {{ option.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

### home.ts:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => 
      option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you include a theme? https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme

Comment: How can do this in ionic apps can you please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

### Include a theme

Including a theme is required to apply all of the core and theme styles to your application.

To get started with a prebuilt theme, include one of Angular Material's prebuilt themes globally in your application. If you're using the Angular CLI, you can add this to your `styles.css`:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

If you are not using the Angular CLI, you can include a prebuilt theme via a `<link>` element in your `index.html`.